# Partial method within partial class error (now with screen shots!)

Tags: c#, wcf

I'm getting an error on my partial method and I'm not sure why. I figure common errors relate to not naming the two partial classes exactly the same and what not, but that's not the case here.

So, I have some generated code, which can be seen here:

[image]

Well, that's not all of it, but I think it's the relevant part.

So, I wanted to create another partial class so I could house these partial methods and get them to have some functionality. So, I created a class and added just one of the functions, as can be seen here, to test:

[image]

Now as I've read the guides online, this should work. I mean obviously I've not understood everything, but I don't know. Oh, here's the error, by the way:

[image]

I guess that's a little hard to read. It says,

> No defining declaration found for implementing declaration of partial method `WCFServiceSQLAccess.DomainContext.HydraDomainDontext.UpdateClients (WCFServiceSQLAccess.DomainContext.Client)`.

Hopefully you can offer some suggestions.

Comment: A screenshot of...text, Seriously ?!

Comment: We seem to be looking at two different classes here... Is that correct? Does your HydraDomainContext define the signature for UpdateClients? Also as a note its better to paste your code in as text rather than images so people can copy and paste sections in their reply if they want to.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's very simple - you've got two different classes: `HydraDomainContext` and `HydraDataContext`. Either change the name of the generated class, or the name of the manually-written class - they'll have to match in order to create one complete class with the partial method implementation matching the declaration.

Answer (score 2):

You have Hydra **Data** Context and Hydra **Domain** Context for the names of the `partial class`.