# How to have Different Partial classes use a Base Class to override same partial Method?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, base-class, partial-classes

After research and [this answer by Mr. Skeet](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8404118/2543557) I don't think this is possible, I just wanted to double check with the community if I missed something or if I can  simplify redundant partial method overrides that look exactly the same from my  Generated Partial Classes.  Here's what I have and what I want to accomplish:

I have many **generated** Partial Classes and Methods.  Each **generated** partial class has the same partial method, `ProccessResponse`, eg:

```
// Generated partial classes/methods
public partial class Item1 {

    partial void ProcessResponse();

    public DoThing1(){
        //some generated business logic stuff
        ProcessResponse();
        //some more generated business logic stuff
   }
}

public partial class Item2 {

    partial void ProcessResponse();

    public DoThing2(){
        //some generated business logic stuff
        ProcessResponse();
        //some more generated business logic stuff
    }
}
```

I want to override logic for `ProcessResponse()` to be the same for all the above partial classes...to do some logging at this point in execution.

I am trying to reduce redundancy of business logic across all my partial classes by not having the same partial method defined for each individual partial class, something like:

```
// Non generated overriding partial classes/methods
public partial class Item1 : BaseClass { }

public partial class Item2 : BaseClass { }

public BaseClass {
    partial void ProcessResponse(){
        // Do The Same thing (logging....) for each partial class/method....
    }
}
```

This doesn't work, the partial method in the above `BaseClass` is not recognized as being the same partial method from the partial class...  Any thoughts or suggestions to accomplish this?  Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

### Update

Ok, based on your description, I thought your idea is to create a [**Builder Design Pattern**](https://www.dotnettricks.com/learn/designpatterns/builder-design-pattern-dotnet).

You can use a combination of interfaces and classes to achieve, here is an extension based on the case you gave:

```
  public interface IBase
    {
        void DoThing1();
        void DoThing2();
        Item GetItem();
    }

    public class MyTestClass : IBase
    {
        private Item _item = new Item();
        public void DoThing1()
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Do thing1!");
            _item.Item1 = "Part1";
        }
        public void DoThing2()
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Do thing2!");
            _item.Item2 = "Part2";
        }
        public Item GetItem()
        {
            return _item;
        }
    }

    public class Item
    {
        public string Item1 { get; set; }
        public string Item2 { get; set; }
    }

    public class TestItem
    {
        private readonly IBase objBase;
        public TestItem(IBase obj)
        {
            objBase = obj;
        }
        public void CreateItem()
        {
            objBase.DoThing1();
            objBase.DoThing2();
        }

        public Item GetItem()
        {
            return objBase.GetItem();
        }
    }
```

Builder Design Pattern Demo:

```
  static async Task Main(string[] args)
  {
     var itemCreator= new TestItem(new MyTestClass());
     itemCreator.CreateItem();
     var item = itemCreator.GetItem();
     Console.ReadKey();
  }
```

Test Result:

[image]

Comment: The partial method is called during the flow of the partial class, this type of processing comes from the generated partial class.  I don't want to call it directly, I want the partial method to be called during it's normal workflow and be overridden, it's just that the same partial method exists across many different partial classes normal workflow.

Comment: @Adam，Do you want to automatically execute the ProcessResponse method when these partial classes are created? If so, you only need to call the ProcessResponse method in the BaseClass constructor to automatically execute it. I have updated my reply.

Comment: No, the partial method execution is part of the partial class workflow, nested inside the generated partial class logic.  I do not want to invoke it manually or on creation, I want the normal workflow to happen in the generated partial class, then when the partial method is called I want to override that method in a base class so I don't have to have multiple partial classes/methods doings the same thing essentially.  I'm going to update my question a bit to reflect this workflow a bit better.

Comment: @Adam, I probably understand your needs, I have updated my answer,  hope it can help you.